# How to add content region to a post or a page

Tags: shortcode, page-template, screen-layout

I need to add a region to a certain pages. Currently our posts are one column. What we need to do is to add region where we could display Table of Contents so it would become two column layout effectively. We would like to be able to add content to the new region so for example we could place shortcode there of the mentioned Table of Content (or any other).

Please have a look at the attached screenshot - on the left hand side there is a TOC and in the main part of the document there is a actual content. How can we do that?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WordPress SE! This is an incredibly broad question that needs to be narrowed down significantly before it can be answered properly. What theme are you using? What editor are you using? Are you looking for a code or a non-code based solution? Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).